# Updating the table by multiple where conditions in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to update the table if only the three values gets matched. I get a syntax error on trying this. What could be the reason?

```
 $sql1="update target set updvalue='".$val3."'  where Id ='".$b."'" AND MId ='".$c."'" AND DID ='".$f."'";
 $res1=$this->db->query($sql1);
```

Comment: What is the syntax error you are getting?

Comment: Do you know [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Comment: I think following [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) would be a quite little work, while they would improve your posts a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql1="update target set updvalue='".$val3."'  where Id ='".$b."' AND MId ='".$c."' AND DID ='".$f."'";
$res1=$this->db->query($sql1);
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

I think there are to many " between where Id and AND, that is, you have made a typo.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16711487)

Comment: @iehrlich this is an answer, as it explains the exact problem. It is not really understandable as it is, so an edit is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Codeigniter query builder.

```
$this->db->where('Id',$b);
$this->db->where('MId',$c);
$this->db->where('DID',$f);
$upd_data['updvalue'] = $val3;
$res1=$this->db->update('target',$upd_data);
```

Let me know if it not works.